# How should I pass the Context object from a Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-mvvm

I recently learned SQLite and know the very basics of MVVM. Was trying to build a simple Notepad Application using these two. In order to, create a database using the SQLiteOpenHelper class I know that we need a Context object. I'm having trouble with how to pass the Context object from a Fragment to the Repository class. Here are the classes:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.view

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var activityMainToolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var activityMainRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var activityMainConstraintLayout: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var activityMainFragmentConstraintLayout: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var activityMainFloatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initializeWidgets()
        initializeToolbar(R.string.app_name)
        setOnClickListenerMethod()
    }

    /**Governing method that overlooks all fragment transactions taking place
     * First, it makes the current ConstraintLayout invisible while bringing the ConstraintLayout designated for the fragments into view.
     * Next, depending on the function to be performed, it then segregates the work functions in:
     * 1. the initializeToolbar() method
     * 2. the performFragmentTransactionMethod() method*/
    private fun initializeFragmentTransactions(fragment: Fragment, toolbarTitle: Int) {
        activityMainConstraintLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        activityMainFragmentConstraintLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        initializeToolbar(toolbarTitle)
        performFragmentTransactionMethod(fragment)
    }

    /**The performFragmentTransactionMethod() is charged simply with changing the current fragment that's present.
     * It takes in the required fragment to be attached as an argument and then changes to it.*/
    private fun performFragmentTransactionMethod(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main_fragment_constraint_layout, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    /**Method to initialize the widgets present in the View*/
    private fun initializeWidgets() {
        activityMainToolbar = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_toolbar_layout)
        activityMainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_recycler_view)
        activityMainFloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_floating_action_button)
        activityMainConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_constraint_layout)
        activityMainFragmentConstraintLayout =
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_fragment_constraint_layout)
    }

    /**Method to initialize the Activity toolbar*/
    private fun initializeToolbar(toolbarTitle: Int) {
        setSupportActionBar(activityMainToolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setTitle(toolbarTitle)
    }

    /**Method to set the onClickListeners for all the required views in the application.*/
    private fun setOnClickListenerMethod() {
        activityMainFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    /**Method to intercept all the clicks performed in the current View*/
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (view == activityMainFloatingActionButton) {
            val addEditFragment = AddEditFragment()
            val titleString: Int = R.string.new_note_string
            initializeFragmentTransactions(addEditFragment, titleString)
        }
    }

    /**Function that checks what to when the back button is pressed.
     * If any fragment is active, it simply means that the activityMainFragmentConstraintLayout is invisible.
     * Therefore, pressing the back button should bring the user back to the home page of the application.
     * In the other case, i.e., the user is present on the main page, the app should exit. */
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (activityMainConstraintLayout.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
            activityMainFragmentConstraintLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            activityMainConstraintLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            initializeToolbar(R.string.app_name)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
}
```

**AddEditFragment.kt**

```
package com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.R
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.model.NotepadEntryPOJO
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class AddEditFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var fragmentAddEditSaveButton: Button
    private lateinit var fragmentAddEditTitleTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var fragmentAddEditSubtitleTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_edit, container, false)
        initializeWidgets(view)
        setOnClickListenerMethod()
        return view
    }

    private fun initiateSaveMethod(notepadEntryPOJO: NotepadEntryPOJO) {
        Log.d(TAG, "initiateSaveMethod: Started")
        mainActivityViewModel.insertDataIntoDatabase(notepadEntryPOJO).observe(this, {
            Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }

    /**OnClick method that handles all the clicks performed in the current view.*/
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (view == fragmentAddEditSaveButton) {
            val titleString: String = fragmentAddEditTitleTextView.text.toString()
            val subtitleString: String = fragmentAddEditSubtitleTextView.text.toString()
            val dateString: String = getDateMethod()
            initiateSaveMethod(NotepadEntryPOJO(titleString, subtitleString, dateString))
        }
    }

    /**Method to get the date using the SimpleDateFormat class*/
    private fun getDateMethod(): String {
        return SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.US).format(Date())
    }

    /**Method to initializeWidgets present in the Fragment.*/
    private fun initializeWidgets(view: View) {
        fragmentAddEditSaveButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_edit_fragment_save_button)
        fragmentAddEditTitleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.add_edit_fragment_title_edit_text)
        fragmentAddEditSubtitleTextView =
            view.findViewById(R.id.add_edit_fragment_subtitle_edit_text)
        mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
    }

    /**Method to intercept all the clicks performed in the current View*/
    private fun setOnClickListenerMethod() {
        fragmentAddEditSaveButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "AddEditFragment"
    }

}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
package com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.model.NotepadEntryPOJO
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.repository.DatabaseRepository

class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val databaseRepository: DatabaseRepository = DatabaseRepository()

    fun insertDataIntoDatabase(notepadEntryPOJO: NotepadEntryPOJO): MutableLiveData<Long> {
        databaseRepository.insertMethod(notepadEntryPOJO)
        return databaseRepository.returnMutableLiveData()
    }
}
```

**DatabaseRepository.kt**

```
package com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.repository

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.provider.BaseColumns
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.model.NotepadContract
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.model.NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper
import com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.model.NotepadEntryPOJO

/**The DatabaseRepository class is tasked with managing all the Database operations.
 * The repository class isn't usually included with the MVVM architecture, but it recommended for best practices.
 * The ViewModel will be communicating with this Repository class to perform all the operations.*/
class DatabaseRepository {
    private val notepadEntryDatabaseHelper: NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper = NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper()

    private val rowMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData()

    /**Method used for performing inserting values into the database */
    fun insertMethod(notepadEntryPOJO: NotepadEntryPOJO) {
        val sqliteDatabase: SQLiteDatabase = notepadEntryDatabaseHelper.writableDatabase
        val insertValues: ContentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, notepadEntryPOJO.title)
            put(NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_SUBTITLE, notepadEntryPOJO.subtitle)
            put(NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_DATE, notepadEntryPOJO.date)
        }

        /*Insert queries usually return a long value signifying the row in which the value has been inserted.
        * The calling method for the insertMethod() will display this returned value as a Toast.*/
        val rowID: Long = sqliteDatabase.insert(
            NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            insertValues
        )

        rowMutableLiveData.postValue(rowID)
    }

    fun returnMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<Long>{
        return rowMutableLiveData
    }

    /**Method for querying all the details present in the database.
     * The details are extracted in a cursor format that is sent to the cursorParseMethod() for extraction.
     * The cursorParseMethod() then returns an ArrayList of type NotepadEntryPOJO to this current method.
     * This method then, promptly, returns the same ArrayList.*/
    fun queryMethod(): ArrayList<NotepadEntryPOJO> {
        val sqLiteDatabase: SQLiteDatabase = notepadEntryDatabaseHelper.readableDatabase
        val sortOrder = "${BaseColumns._ID} DESC"

        /*The projection specifies the exact columns from which we want to extract data from the database.
        * In this case, the column ID is being omitted as it isn't quite usable in the Views.*/
        val projection = arrayOf(
            NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
            NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_DATE
        )

        /*The cursor object extract only the columns as specified in the projection array.
        * In this case, it extracts all the columns with the exception of the ID column.
        * The ID column is being used only for sorting the values into a descending order.*/
        val cursor: Cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
            NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        )

        return cursorParseMethod(cursor)
    }

    /**The cursorParseMethod() takes an argument of type Cursor.
     * It queries this cursor object and extract all the files into a separate ArrayList.
     * This ArrayList is sent back to the query method.*/
    private fun cursorParseMethod(cursor: Cursor): ArrayList<NotepadEntryPOJO> {
        val databaseItems: ArrayList<NotepadEntryPOJO> = ArrayList()

        with(cursor) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val titleItem = getString(getColumnIndex(NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_TITLE))
                val subtitleItem =
                    getString(getColumnIndex(NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_SUBTITLE))
                val dateItem = getString(getColumnIndex(NotepadContract.NotepadEntry.COLUMN_DATE))
                databaseItems.add(NotepadEntryPOJO(titleItem, subtitleItem, dateItem))
            }
        }

        return databaseItems
    }
}
```

**NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper.kt**

```
package com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.model

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

/**The DatabaseHelper class used for initializing for performing initial database operations*/
class NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(
    context,
    NotepadContract.DATABASE_NAME,
    null,
    NotepadContract.DATABASE_VERSION
) {

    /**The onCreate method is used for initially creating the database.*/
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db!!.execSQL(NotepadContract.SQLITE_CREATE_ENTRY)
    }

    /**The onUpgrade is used when we want to upgrade database.
     * Usually upgrade refers to when we add more columns or remove them and other such operations.*/
    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

    }

}
```

Currently, the line:

```
 private val notepadEntryDatabaseHelper: NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper = NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper()
```

is showing an error as there's no Context object being passed in there. I was wondering how I could accomplish this. I thought about creating a method in the DatabaseRepository.kt class that would initialize the object everytime we needed it, i.e. initializing the object at the beginning of the insertMethod() and queryMethod().

But I was also apprehensive about this, particularly, wouldn't this cause too many objects to be created?

Another thing that I wanted to mention was that I tried to pass the Context object by creating a constructor for the MainActivityViewModel class. But it constantly caused an error, namely:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.kotlin.thenotepadapplication.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
```

I assumed this was because when I was creating an instance of the ViewModel class in my Fragment, i.e., in the line

```
mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

I wasn't actually passing the constructor argument for the Context object. As a result, the app was crashing down everytime.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to pass `context` from `ViewModel` to `Repository` use `AndroidViewModel` which can take applicationContext also needs instance to be created.

Also check the [android documentation here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

So make these changes

ViewModel class:

```
class MainActivityViewModel(
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
   // Access context from application, pass it to Repository
}
```

Repository class:

```
class DatabaseRepository(
    context: Context
) { 
    // Pass context to Helper class
    NotepadEntryDatabaseHelper(context)
}
```

Now you need this class for creating the instance for `AndroidViewModel`.

Factory class:

```
class ActiityViewModelFactory(
    private val application: Application
) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(YourViewModelClass::class.java)) {
            return YourViewModelClass(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create instance for class ViewModelClass")
    }
}
```

Now in your activity or fragment you need to pass factory along with viewModel, like this:

Fragment or Activity class :

```
val factory = YourViewModelFactory(application)
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(YourViewModelFactory::class.java)
```

Hope this works. Let me know further if you get error.

Comment: I thought about using AndroidViewModel but the other answer recommended against it. And a little research also said that passing context objects into ViewModels wouldn't be right. I'm thinking of learning about the Room library. I've noticed that it is a preferred way to persisting data in MVVM.

Comment: Yes, using dagger is recommended too, also not necessary for lite applications because dagger itself is a huge concept and you are free to learn.   Now speaking of ViewModels, see AndroidViewModel is a subclass of ViewModel that is aware of the Application context, so in this case you can use it. You can see here for AndroidViewModel documentation [ https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel ].

Comment: You can learn Room database, which is much easier to implement and work along with MVVM. You can check this project which uses Room with MVVM.  https://github.com/RajashekarRaju/ProjectSubmission-GoogleDevelopers

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Dependence Injection like Dagger. And you will bind a Context when you initialize like this:

```
 @Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class,ViewModelModule::class])
interface AppComponent{

    @Component.Factory
    interface  Factory{
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(categoryFragment: CategoryFragment)
    fun inject(categoriesFragment: CategoriesFragment)
    fun inject(expensesFragment: ExpensesFragment)
    fun inject(listExpensesFragment: ListExpensesFragment)
    fun inject(reportFragment: ReportFragment)

}
```

And here is the way you create an instance of Database

```
  @Module
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(context: Context): ExpenseTrackerDB {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, ExpenseTrackerDB::class.java, Constant.DB_NAME)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCategoryDao(db: ExpenseTrackerDB): CategoryDao {
        return db.categoryDao()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideExpenseDao(db: ExpenseTrackerDB): ExpenseDao {
        return db.expenseDao()
    }

}
```

And here is the way you bind a contenxt

```
open class ExpenseTrackerApplication: Application() {

    open val appComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }

}
```

I built an example, check it in here:
https://github.com/frank-nhatvm/expensestracker

There is another way: use AndroidViewModel. But you shouldn't use it

Comment: I'm yet to learn Dependency Injection and like you said, I'll avoid AndroidViewModel. I researched a bit and found out the problems with passing context into ViewModels. I think a better alternative would be to learn about the Room library in that case. What do you think? I've learnt about SQLite and it makes sense, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Yes, you should learn Room. Because Google built Room library to help us work with Database easier. Check my sample, I used Room and Dependency Injection.